# Stuck at SQL Join Query

Tags: mysql, database

I am newbie to database. I have the following tables

```
Customer (customer_id, customer_name, city)
Order (order_id, order_date, customer_id)
Order_Item (order_id, item_id, quantity)
Item (item_id, unit_price)
Shipment (order_id, warehouse_id, ship_date)
Warehouse (warehouse_id, warehouse_name, warehouse_city)
```

The required queries are :

- Write a SQL query to retrieve count of items and total price of each order.
- Write a SQL query to retrieve total price of orders that have been shipped from warehouse with name “FridaHouse”.

this is my attempt for the first query but for sure it doesn't work out

```
SELECT item.item_id, SUM(item.unit_price * order_item.quantity) AS TOTAL_PRICE 
FROM order_item JOIN item on item.item_id=order_item.item_id;
```

Comment: what was the error you have received? What have you tried for the second query?

Comment: Read the requirement properly: "Write a SQL query to retrieve count of items and total price of each order". It is one row per order you want to show and each row is supposed to contain the item count and the total price. It makes no sense to select item_id. And you are joining the item table. What does it contain that you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a group_by clause, telling SQL to aggregate all rows with the same order_id. Also, you should be returning the id for the order, not for the item (there can be different items in an order, so SQL wouldn't know which one to return). Minus possible typos, the first query should look something like this:

```
select
  order_id,
  sum(quantity) as quantity,
  sum(unit_price*quantity) as total_price
from order_item join item on item.item_id = order_item.item_id
group by order_id
```

This assumes that ever order contains at least one item - if you want to cater for empty orders, select from orders and perform a left outer join with the subquery above.